# Invalid procedure call error in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook

I have the below function which takes in a string (the path to the file) and should read in unicode (because I'm getting glyphs being returned and suspect it is the character encoding being wrong - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278834(v=office.15).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278834%28v=office.15%29.aspx)).

The code error's out with `5 Invalid procedure call or argument`.

Here's the function:

```
Function readFile(pathIn As String) As String
On Error GoTo err_handle:
    Const ForReading = 1
    Const TristateTrue = -1

    Dim oFSO As FileSystemObject
    Set oFSO = New FileSystemObject

    Dim oFS As TextStream

    If oFSO.FileExists(pathIn) Then
        Set oFS = oFSO.OpenTextFile(pathIn, ForReading, False, TristateTrue)
        GoTo return_string:
    Else
        Debug.Print ("inVar file cannot exist!")
        readFile = "ERROR"
    End If

    Exit Function

return_string:
    readTxtFile = oFS.ReadAll
    oFS.Close
    Exit Function
err_handle:
    Debug.Print ("Error in readFile()[B]: " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description)
    readFile = "ERROR"
    oFS.Close
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Any ideas?

**ANSWER:**

Needed to use -2 instead of -1.

Comment: On what line does the error get raised?

Comment: Remove the On error line and the next two lines (Const lines) and see where the error occurs.

Comment: Solved it. I needed to use value -2, instead of -1.

Answer (score 0):

> Const TristateTrue = -1

You have the wrong value for your `TristateTrue` constant. It should be 1 for Unicode. -1 is not one of the [possible values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265347%28v=vs.60%29.aspx).

Comment: It is -1 on MSoft's article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278834(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: So it is! The plot thickens. Evidently MS changed it at some point... so it will depend on which version of the COM object you have registered. I take it you're trying other values?

Comment: COM object? What version do I need? You're talking about the Object Library (Tools > References), yes?

Comment: The argument is a bit moot; You are early binding via a reference so there is no need to define TristateTrue or ForReading yourself as they are exposed already by the COM object itself, just type them.

Comment: @Alex K, Good point. So, @uncle-junky, for example, using Excel 2007, if I use Tools, References to add a reference to Microsoft.Scripting.Runtime, and delete your coded constants, then after I type the comma after `pathIn`, intellisense pops up the possible values for the next argument, which are ForAppending, ForReading, ForWriting. Those constants will have the correct value for the version of the FileSystemObject I'm currently using, so I don't need to worry about what values they should have. FWIW your code runs fine for me in that environment.

Answer (score 0):

Needed to use -2 instead of -1, though not sure if this is unicode or not. All I wanted to do really was read in a UTF-8 format. -2 corresponds to the system default according to the article linked above. I don't know what this is, but it works in any case.